# Cassandra :Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with 3 nodes. I have a movies_keyspace with replication factor of 1 so only one copy of each record exists. It contains a movies table which has 3 records. When my first node was up and the other two were down I fired the select * from movies query and it is giving me "Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable"(this has been answered in other threads). However, when I fire select * from movies where title="movie_name" for all the three movies added it is returning me rows. How is this possible when the other two nodes are down? I should be getting the earlier error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `select * from table`, A cassandra coordinator node creates range requests for each token range in your ring.  Since you have a keyspace with a replication factor of 1 that means each node must be available to successfully issue all range queries.  Since 2 of the 3 ranges have no replicas available, Cassandra returns an 'Unavailable' error.

As for `select * from movies where title='X'` succeeding, what is likely is that each of these titles must belong in the same range.

If you'd like to verify this, you can use the `nodetool getendpoints keyspace_name table_name key` command. For example, if I have a cluster with 3 nodes and a keyspace 'test' with a replication factor of 3, `nodetool getendpoints test table1 1` returns:

```
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
127.0.0.1
```

If I alter my keyspace and reduce my replication factor to 1, the same query now returns only 1 node:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE test
WITH replication = {
    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
    'replication_factor' : 3
};
```

`nodetool getendpoints test table1 1`:

```
127.0.0.2
```

Cassandra uses [Partitioning](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Partitioners) to determine placement of data based on this primary key.  Thus, if I change my key, I may get a different node back:

`nodetool getendpoints test table1 32342349`:

```
127.0.0.1
```

`nodetool getendpoints test table1 32342344`:

```
127.0.0.3
```

If you experiment with this with the 3 movie titles where the query works, does it always return the same endpoint?

Comment: The nodetool returns me the same node for each of the movie titles. Every time I get 127.0.0.2.

Comment: shouldn't it be giving me 3 different nodes for the 3 movies?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Cassandra calculates what nodes owns what data based on it's Partitioner (http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Partitioners) and the primary key of the data you are attempting to retrieve.